# SDL_GetKeyboardState not working

Tags: c, input, keyboard, sdl

I am trying to make a controller for a game with SDL 2(didn't want to ask on gamedev since it is not a game issue directly) I use SDL_GetKeyboardEvent to see if the navigation arrows are being pressed but it apparently doesn't work, it is supposed to print a value 1 or -1 if one of those keys is pressed but it doesn't it just prints 0 even if I hold the key down for several seconds, it is like it doesn't detect that the key is being pressed. I searched all over the internet and this is how they do it, but it doesn't work for me.

```
#define SDL_MAIN_HANDLED
#include <stdio.h>
#include "SDL.h"

/* I'll add some code later
so something that isn't used
might be initialized
*/
int main (void)
{
    int a = 1;
    int x;
    int z;
    SDL_Event quit;
    const Uint8 *keys = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);

    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

    while(a)
    {
        SDL_PollEvent(&quit);
        if(quit.type == SDL_QUIT)
            a = 0;

        if(keys[SDL_SCANCODE_UP])
            z = 1;
        else if(keys[SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN])
            z = -1;
        else
            z = 0;
        if(keys[SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT])
            x = -1;
        else if(keys[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT])
            x = 1;
        else
            x = 0;
        printf("%d, %d\n", x, z);
//This is supposed to print
//x, z values so if up arrow is pressed it will print 0, 1 and if
//down arrow is pressed it will print 0, -1: the same with horizontal ones.
//1 or -1, 1 or -1
    }

    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [No SDL Keypress events being detected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/257275/no-sdl-keypress-events-being-detected)

Comment: It is not a duplicate, that question uses an entire different method and SDL 1.x while I'm using SDL 2, so many things are entirely different.

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation: [wiki](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetKeyboardState)

`Note: This function gives you the current state after all events have been processed, so if a key or button has been pressed and released before you process events, then the pressed state will never show up in the SDL_GetKeyboardState() calls`

What it means is?

You need to process all events. How? Looping the `PollEvent`, after the loop (or if you want to check in the loop, check at the end), the `SDL_GetKeyboardState` is usable.

So, go through the loop, check for keyboards states. Do not forget to always go through the loop before checking for keys

e.g.

```
while (game)
    {
        /*! updates the array of keystates */
        while ((SDL_PollEvent(&e)) != 0)
        {
            /*! request quit */
            if (e.type == SDL_QUIT) 
            { 
                game = false;
            }
        }

        if (keys[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT])
            std::cout << "Right key";
    }
```

Comment: So that means I just need to use SDL_PollEvent after checking all the keys and not before?

Comment: you just need to "run" PollEvent (the loop), and GetKeyboardState will be completed

Comment: Well, it already is inside the loop, I tried putting it before the loop and it didn't work then I put it after the loop and it doesn't work.

Comment: I tried following you example but it still doesn't work. And I'm using C BTW. Is it possible that something is wrong with the keyboard codification or something?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a window with `SDL_SetVideoMode` to get mouse and keyboard events.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my InputManager update function that updates the user input from the keyboard and mouse. Notice the `const_cast` needed to be able to update the class variable `Uint8* keysArray;`. This way, more than one event can be processed at once.

```
    void update() {
        SDL_PumpEvents();

        // update keyboard state
        keysArray = const_cast <Uint8*> (SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL));

        if (keysArray[SDL_SCANCODE_RETURN])
            printf("MESSAGE: <RETURN> is pressed...\n");
        if (keysArray[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT] && keysArray[SDL_SCANCODE_UP])
            printf("MESSAGE: Right and Up arrows are pressed...\n");

        // update mouse location and button states
        SDL_GetMouseState(&x, &y);
        getMouseButtonStates();
}
```