# SDL_GetKeyboardState does not return the current state of a key

Tags: c++, c, keyboard, sdl, sdl-2

I'm using SDL 2.0, and I can't get `SDL_GetKeyboardState` to work as expected. The player should move up and down, but this is not happening.

```
void Movements() {

    const Uint8  *currentKey = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);  // Point has to be defined once

    if (currentKey[SDLK_w]){
            PlayerPaddle.y = PlayerPaddle.y+2;
        }

    if (currentKey[SDLK_s]){
            PlayerPaddle.y = PlayerPaddle.y+2;
        }

}

int main(int argc, char* args[]) {

    main_menue();

    bool running = true;

    while (running == true) {
        SDL_PollEvent(&occur);

        if (occur.type == SDL_QUIT) {  // Closes the window, if user stops running
            running = false;
        }
        Movements();
    }
}
```

I also tried to pump up the event loop with `PumpEvents`, but still can't read the current state of a key. I also found this on stackoverflow ([SDL_GetKeyboardState not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23328847/sdl-getkeyboardstate-not-working)), but the answers there did not help me find a solution. Did I miss something here? Am I really blind and misunderstood something?

Comment: Without seeing your code in it's complete form, it's too haard to say. You don't have any SDL initialization code here or any error checking.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `SDL_Init()` and other declarations were just removed when pasting here.

First, you are not using correct indexes.
As explained [in the documentation here](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetKeyboardState) : "Indexes into this array are obtained by using [SDL_Scancode values](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Scancode)." But you are using  SDL_Keycode values.

The other problem is that you are using the non-blocking `SDL_PollEvent` and calling `Movements()` at each iteration, and don't have any kind of blocking or waiting in your loop. This will use 100% CPU, running as fast as possible, and you'll end up with a pretty high `y` value ...

Instead of the array returned by `SDL_GetKeyboardState` you could use the key events. If `occur.type` is for instance `SDL_KEYDOWN`, `occur.key.keysym.sym` is the `SDL_Keycode` of the pressed key. Look at the documentation of [`SDL_Event`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Event) and other event types for the details.

You should also add a `SDL_Delay` to your loop.

Another way is to use [`SDL_WaitEvent`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_WaitEvent) which only returns when an event occurs. Then you process the event, if it is a key press do some action depending on the key, etc ...